# How to use sub contexts in Behat 3.0

Tags: symfony, bdd, behat

in behat 2.5 if i want split my step definitions i only need create multiple clases

```
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext
{    
    public function __construct(array $parameters)
    {
        // Initialize your context here
        // ...
        $this->useContext('SubContextA', new SubContextA($parameters));
        $this->useContext('SubContextB', new SubContextB($parameters));
    }
}
```

but the 3.0 branch is quite different the Context dont extends they implements SnippetAcceptingContext and use traits like KernelDictionary for example.

How i can use "subcontexts" in Behat 3.0 the documentation is really poor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation is really poor indeed. AFAIK you don't have sub contexts, instead you now can [define multiple contexts](http://behat.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guides/5.suites.html#suite-contexts) per suite.

```
# behat.yml

default:
    suites:
        domain_features:
            paths:    [ %paths.base%/features ]
            contexts: [ DomainContext ]
        web_features:
            paths:    [ %paths.base%/features ]
            contexts: [ WebContext ]
            filters:
                tags: @web
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this still only allows you to only have one context that extends MinkContext. To make this possible you'll have to make use of scenario hooks: http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/cookbooks/accessing_contexts_from_each_other.html

Comment: Indeed. Typically you'd extend `MinkContext` for very specific use. Normally it should be `RawMinkContext` or something lower.